# How to print a string from another function?

Tags: python, function

Hello i need print mystring inside "functionone" from another function and i did this:

```
def functionone():

    mystring = "This word from functionone!"

def functiontwo():

    print(mystring)
```

But it doesn't work. How i can do this correctly?

Comment: In general, you should not do this.  If `functionone` needs to produce a value for use by others, it should RETURN that value.  If `functiontwo` needs input, it should be a parameter to the function.

Comment: How i can do this?

Comment: What you're asking for there is global variables.  They are, in general, poor practice.

Comment: I suggest that you look up "python function scope" or similar in Google. It's not good for people here to be guessing what you want to do - instead, empower yourself by learning what this means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def functionone():
    return "This word from functionone!"

def functiontwo():
    print(functionone())
```

Or even:

```
def functionone():
    return "This word from functionone!"

def functiontwo(msg):
    print(msg)

functiontwo( functionone() )
```

You CAN do what you ask using globals, but this is poor practice and leads to difficult-to-find errors.

```
def functionone():
    global mystring
    mystring = "This word from functionone!"

def functiontwo():
    print(mystring)
```

Comment: probably im gonna use globals because i need get a value from another function like this: "rnd = Random.new().read(16)"

Comment: @CodexSC: Look at the second example, how you can return values from functions and then use them as parameters in other functions. You don't need globals and, even if they seem intuitive at first, in the long term they're a bad practice.

Comment: Right.  A single function can return several things.  That makes the output of the function explicit, instead of implicit.  What you're doing is called a "side effect" -- the function changes global state unexpectedly.

Answer (score -4):

you need to call your function try this:

```
def functionone():

mystring = "This word from functionone!"
print(mystring)

def functiontwo()
    functionone()
```